# Is there a new distribution in 2019?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems that every year release a new ros distribution, why not in 2019?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332364/is-there-a-new-distribution-in-2019?/) by [Panason](https://answers.ros.org/users/44410/panason/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q324973.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1